# Cloud messaging in RabbitMQ

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, rabbitmq, messaging, spring-rabbit

I'm trying to implement functionality similar to Google Cloud Messaging. I want to send message from server side, and retrive same message on Android device.  I chose RabbitMQ as an "engine". On the client side I created listener and bind it to queue.
In some cases I want to send message to every device. And it's working. But in other cases I want to send message to one specific device. Is it possible?
I saw that in message metadata is field consumer tag, that is unique. How can I send message to that specific consumer tag?

Comment: like this ? https://www.cloudamqp.com/

Comment: No. I already have RabbitMQ instance. And everything working.
Question is, if I can send message to only one device? And how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

RabbitMQ (AMQP) has no concept of a message selector; you need a separate queue for each device. You can use a [topic exchange to route to individual (or all) devices using an appropriate routing key](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-java.html).

Comment: As I thougth... I already did that way. But I also thought, that maybe there is some "more nice" way to do this.

Comment: I read that RabbitMQ supports MQTT. I also read, that Facebook using MQTT to push messages. Maye there is some way, to connect to RabbitMQ queue as MQTT client?

Comment: You can use eclipse Paho - the Spring Integration project [here](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/) has implementations of [MQTT adapters based on Paho documented here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mqtt.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send message to specific consumer, look at direct exchange http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-java.html

Comment: @MatMie I saw this example already. And it's working for 2-3 devices. But I'm curious if it'll be working for ie. 1000+ devices. I'm not sure if it's efficient. I'm looking for "dedicated" to that solution. 
Anybody did push messaging that way?